# Foundation inside and outside of house cracking

Tags: walls, foundation, cracks

I have a problem with my 60 year old back-split home that the concrete is cracking everywhere.  We have cracks in the ceiling above the stairs leading the bedroom level, a vertical crack in the basement wall, cracks all over the lower basement floor, the concrete outside the front door is cracked, the concrete front step is cracked and crumbling, the pool has two very big cracks on the surface of the sidewalk poured around it (not the walls of the pool and it is not a concrete pool), the new floor poured in our pool house sank 2 inches and lastly the concrete wall that surrounds the stairs leading to the first level basement walkout is cracking.  Is our house falling down or is this fixable?? Please help!

Comment: Are you sure these are new? It is common for these cracks (minor or major) to have been there for years and they are only in the back of your head but you don't really notice until you go looking for them.  Have there been any changes to the ground around your home on the outside, is your property flat or on a hill, have your neighbors experienced any issues; all questions to look at before hiring the professionals.  You mention a new floor in the pool house, how recent? have you spoken to that contractor about the sinking?

Answer (score 2):

This isn't what you want to hear, but you may already know the answer: it's time to call a pro. Issues with concrete foundations aren't for even the most hardcore DIY-ers.